# Setting up GoSquared tracking across multiple subdomains

Tags: cookies, tracking, subdomain

I've been looking around the GoSquared website and am struggling to see how I setup the tracking to work across multiple subdomains for the same site. My site basically works like this:

```
auth.mysite.com
store.mysite.com
community.mysite.com
```

These site areas are heavily linked to one another and it's quite easy for users to move from one to the next.

Now I've noticed the cookie that GoSquared creates `'gs_u'` has set its domain as `store.mysite.com` which leads me to think when the user hits `auth.` or `community.` that it will not track them there, and possibly even create additional cookies for each subdomain.

Is it possible to get GoSquared to work across multiple subdomains cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the tracking code sets the domain on the visitor's cookie to the same as the location domain. When the visitor navigates to a different subdomain, the cookie will not be transferred over and the visitor appears as a new visitor.

It's on our TODO to allow developers to specify the domain to set the cookie with, however this is currently not supported by the tracking code. I will try to post back here once we have it implemented.

Thanks for using GoSquared!

Geoff Wagstaff

CTO

GoSquared

Comment: Cool, thank you for the rapid response. I'll accept this answer and you can update in future.